# Kubuntu not allowing me to install npm

Tags: kubuntu, npm

Recently I moved to using kubuntu from mint, and when I tried to install npm I got the following error

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to
resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libssl-dev : Depends:
libssl3 (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu1) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.6 is to be installed E:
Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is there a way for me to solve this or will I need to find a different distribution if I wish to work with npm?

Comment: The first detail needed in package issues are the release you're using.  Are we to guess?  Kubuntu is a Ubuntu *flavor*, thus all packages included are only those found in Ubuntu repositories, meaning packaging issues will be identical to Ubuntu for the *unstated* release.

Comment: Your packages appear out of date & are requesting an *outdated* package (*which is based on guess you're using jammy as you didn't specify; are you using Ubuntu/Kubuntu?*).  Refer https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libssl-dev&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all and https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libssl3&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all where expected would be https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/libssl3  so return to basics; `sudo apt update` & read messages; all lines there & none missing, no issues... etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)